# finding element of numpy array that satisfies condition

Tags: python, search, numpy

One can use `numpy`'s `extract` function to match an element in an array. The following code matches an element `'a.'` exactly in an array. Suppose I want
to match all elements containing `'.'`, how would I do that? Note that in this case, there would be two matches. I'd also like to get the row and column number of the matches. The method doesn't have to use `extract`; any method will do. Thanks.

```
In [110]: x = np.array([['a.','cd'],['ef','g.']])

In [111]: 'a.' == x
Out[111]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [112]: np.extract('a.' == x, x)
Out[112]: 
array(['a.'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Comment: It would be less confusing to write `x == 'a.'`, not that it helps answer you question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [string operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html#string-information):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([['a.','cd'],['ef','g.']])
>>> x[np.char.find(x, '.') > -1]
array(['a.', 'g.'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

**EDIT:** As per request in the comments... If you want to find out the indexes of where the target condition is true, use [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(np.char.find(x, '.') > -1)
(array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]))
```

or

```
>>> zip(*np.where(np.char.find(x, '.') > -1))
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: Nice, never knew about `char`

Comment: Thanks. Any way of finding the row and column?

Comment: @mac: See comment at the bottom of the main question. I couldn't fit it into SO's notion of a comment.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Sorry, my bad. You should compare with `>-1` as `0` is the valid positional index for "found as first character"... (You should probably remove the edited part if it solves, as it will only confuse future visitors...).

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([['a.','cd'],['ef','g.']])
>>> selector = np.array(['.' in s for s in x.flat]).reshape(x.shape)
>>> x[selector]
array(['a.', 'g.'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way of finding the row and column?